# Django CMS: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'subject_location' after deleting an image plugin

Tags: django

Im exploring Django CMS on Divio for one of my sites. Running into an issue when I delete an image that is being used by a picture plugin.

Getting:

""" 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'subject_location'"""

The home page is trying to access the image but it doesn't exist hence throwing the error above. However, I am unable to access CMS page to change the image to one that exists.

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by just deleting the page from within the admin site and recreating it from scratch. Not a very satisfactory solution, but workable.

You can do this from the `admin/cms/page/` endpoint. If you ended up deleting your homepage, you can set it as "home" again from within this view, too, using the Burger menu "Set as Home" function.